# Position: sticky on table head in React issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sticky

I'm creating a table in react and would like the header row to be sticky. It works as I like, except for this weird issue I'm experience in Chrome. If you look at the picture, rows 1-4 have a bunch of extra horizontal lines across them. Every time I scroll down, new horizontal lines are made and the old ones disappear. I've researched the issue and haven't been able to find any similar issues. Any idea what's going on?  My code is below.

[image: The extra lines in rows 1-4 happen when I scroll down.]

```
const ReusableTable = props => (
     <table className={"table sticky-table"}>
       <thead className={styles.stickyHead}>
         <tr>
           <th> Item </th>
             {
               props.fields[0].map(row => <th key={row.key}> {row.title} 
               </th>)
             }
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        {
          props.fields.map((row, index) => {
          return (
           <tr key={index}>
             <td> {index + 1} </td>
              {row.map((attributes, indx) => {
                if (!attributes.clickable) {
                 return <td key={indx}> {attributes.value} </td>
              }
              else {
                return <td key={indx} onClick={props.clickableTD} style= 
                {props.styling}> {attributes.value} </td>
               }
             })}
           </tr>
          )
         })
        }
       </tbody>
      </table>
     );
```

and the css

```
.stickyHead {
   background-color: #000000;
   color: #ffffff;
   border: none;
   outline: 0;
 }


 .stickyHead th {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  td {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
  }
```

Comment: that's strange. Is there any styling that can be seen via the chrome inspector? What happens if you comment out the styles? Is it possible to narrow down which one of them might be causing the issue?

Comment: what's the body look like?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I narrowed it down to the table class. Still don't know why bootstrap caused the issue, but I'll just give it custom css.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was from Bootstrap. I removed the table class and the problem has been fixed.

Edit: I gutted the Bootstrap for custom css and got the same issue when I gave the tr tags a border-bottom. I gave each td tag the border-bottom instead and problem solved.